# Generating data with given regression coefficients

Tags: regression, random-generation

I would like to generate data points with given regression coefficients, where some of the variables may be discrete and some continuous, and I am performing both "direct" and "reverse" regressions.

For example, I would like to generate data points consisting of triples $(x,y,z)$ where $x$ is either 0 or 1 and $y$ and $z$ are real, such that when one (linearly) regresses $z$ on the other two variables ($z_i=\alpha x_i+\beta y_i+\epsilon_i$), I have some given regression coefficients ($\alpha$ and $\beta$).  Simultaneously, I would like to specify the coefficients when one regresses y on the other two variables.  (As an added complication, I would also like to specify the regression coefficients of $z$ and $y$ conditioned on the different values of $x$.)  The difficulty arises, naturally, due to the fact that I would like control of both of these regressions simultaneously.

How would I go about doing this systematically?

Comment: I think this is going to be pretty complicated. A couple of additional pieces of information would help. 1) Do you want practical help generating these, or to understand the ideas behind it theoretically? 2) What software are you using? 3) Do you want data from that *population*, or you want to actually get those specific parameter values back when you regress? 4) Can you say something about the distributions you want, eg do you want normally distributed data? In general, the more specific you can be the more we can help you.

Comment: 1) Either actually, but I think it would be much more educational for me to actually be able to generate data in practice.  2) I'm okay with anything: R, Matlab, SAS, Mathematica, hand-coded C.  3) Population.  4) I don't care whether the data is normal.  It's fine if it is.

Comment: Fundamentally, I see the problem as follows: there are known techniques for generating data with given marginal and conditional distributions.  Are there similar methods for generating data with given regression coefficients?  And furthermore, what is the easiest way to actually do so with existing software?

Comment: Len Stefanski [in this work](http://www4.stat.ncsu.edu/~stefanski/NSF_Supported/Hidden_Images/stat_res_plots.html) does the first part of what you want. The "added complication" does not sound feasible, to me, at least outside of balanced designs.